# Check if product has variants. How to?

Tags: product, magento-2.0

How do I  check if product has used  Products. I use the following snippet to get child products

```
$variants = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
```

however if product does not have any child products this would generate a fatal error. So first I would like to check if product has any childs. How would I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear.

Are you simply asking how to determine if the product is a complex product (so can have/can have children, or if it is s simple product (so cannot have children)

If so, you'd simply check the product type:

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
            // YOUR CODE HERE
        }
```